# I do not understand why does the sendMessage method is missing from the getDefaultChannel()

Tags: missing-data

I am working on a discord bot in java and I want to add the possibility where the bot sends a message of users' status when it changes. However i am unable to find that method to send message in the defaultChannel when in the video i am following is clearly there.

```
@Override
public void onUserUpdateOnlineStatus(UserUpdateOnlineStatusEvent event) {
    super.onUserUpdateOnlineStatus(event);
    User user = event.getUser();
    String message = "**" + user.getAsTag() + "** updated their status!";
    event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel().sendMessage(message).queue();
```

[image]

I have tried to enable all the intents for the bot and even gave it administrative permission.

Answer (score 0):

```
event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel().asStandardGuildMessageChannel().sendMessage(message).queue();
```

5.0.0-alpha.20 and asStandardGuildMessageChannel() between getDefaultChannel() and sendMessage